# Why is it important to know a family of functions has compact closure?

Tags: functional-analysis, intuition

In Brezis' book on functionnal analysis, the author sais that

> It is important to be able to decide whether a family of functions in
> $L^p (\mathbb{R})$ has compact closure in $L^p (\mathbb{R})$ (for the strong topology).

Also, I guess that this is important as well in $C^0(I)$ since it is the subject of Arzelà-Ascoli theorem.

But why is this important intuitively(or not)?

Answer (score 1):

Because then any sequence of functions of the family will have a convergent subsequence. So, if $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a famliy of approximate solutions of a problem, in which the aproximations keep getting better, and if $(f_{n_k})_{k\in\Bbb N}$ is a subsequence converging to $f$, then $f$ might be a solution of that problem.